# $sr_no =~ s/^(0*)(.*)/$2/ , what does mean in perl script?

Tags: regex, perl

What is the meaning for the below substitution?

```
if($sr_no =~ m/^0/)
{
    $sr_no =~ s/^(0*)(.*)/$2/;
}
```

Comment: Note that it will blank out a string consisting only of zeroes rather than leaving one behind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a clumsy way of writing `$sr_no =~ s/^0+//`, that is, remove any leading zeros. The `if` is basically useless, as the substitution performs the same logic anyway (i.e. does not substitute if there is no match).

Answer (score 6):

It strips leading zeros from a string.

Although I'd write it as

```
s/^0+//
```

i.e. replace one or more (`+`) leading (`^`) zeros (`0`) with nothing (`//`).

Answer (score 2):

Replace all( due to `*`) preceding (due to `^`) zeros by everything that followed them (due to `$2 = (.*)`)

Answer (score 2):

- If the content of the scalar variable `sr_no` matches the regular expression `^0`

  - that is, starts with a `0`
- Replace the text matching the regular expression `^(0*)(.*)` with the second group

  - that is, remove leading `0`s.

See also:

- [Perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for background information about reguar expressions in Perl
- [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) for detailed information about the `m//` and `s///` operators.